SonarQube: Invoke method(s) only conditionally - logger executes not needed functions
Aren't loggers in Java supposed to execute functions in the arguments only if the log level is reached?
So here in my example I would have assumed that "Did additional work" would only appear once. What am I missing here?
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Slf4j
public class LogTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        runDebug();
        runInfo();
    }

    private void runInfo() {
        log.info("hi @ info {}", additional());
    }

    public void runDebug() {
        log.debug("hello @ debug {}", additional());
    }

    private String additional() {
        log.info("Did additional work...");
        return "sup";
    }
}

Console output:
15:10:28.249 [main] INFO test.LogTest -- Did additional work...
15:10:28.252 [main] INFO test.LogTest -- Did additional work...
15:10:28.252 [main] INFO test.LogTest -- hi @ info sup

PS. I read SonarQube: Invoke method(s) only conditionally and SonarQube: "Invoke method(s) only conditionally". I think I understood those, but in my case it doesn't seem to work correctly. In my work project I have a similar case and SonarQube is saying it's an issue.

As Rob Spoor's answer says, it is impossible for an argument not to be evaluated before being passed to a method, and log.debug gets called only after all its arguments are evaluated. However, most logging libraries (other than Slf4j) allow you to pass lambdas, and the logging method only evaluates the lambda if the level is high enough such that the log would be printed. For example, log4j2 allows this:
log.debug("hello @ debug {}", () -> additional());

or even more succinctly:
log.debug(() -> "hello @ debug " + additional());

Similarly, java.util.logging allows this:
log.log(DEBUG, () -> "hello @ debug " + additional());

Unfortunately, in slf4j the syntax for passing a lambda is very verbose:
log.atDebug().setMessage("hello @ debug {}").addArgument(() -> additional()).log();

Thus, people who don't want to use this new "fluent" API due to its verbosity would have to use the old-style way (which is still much shorter than the new way):
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("hello @ debug {}", additional());


I never knew that Log4j2 allows each argument to be provided as suppliers, that's pretty cool.

That does look good. But we use Slf4j in our project. So I cannot use this I guess... Unless we migrate to log4j.

@PatrickRode you can still use the if (log.isDebugEnabled()) { log.debug(...); } solution to make SonarQube happy. I've done that often enough.

Yep, i'll do it. I don't like it though :> But in most cases we have INFO logs. SonarQube is still complaining. But for those I will just mark them as false positives, as we will pretty much always show all info logs. For Debug I would use exactly what you've posted. Thanks!

In log.debug("hello @ debug {}", additional()), the additional() is a method call executed right there, right then. The logger doesn't magically change the way Java works. The only conditional method calls in logging are calls to toString() if you provide an object as logger argument.
For instance:
// method-local class for demo purposes
class Argument {

    public Argument() {
        log.info("argument created");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        log.info("toString() invoked");
        return "this is an argument";
    }
}

log.debug("hello @debug {}", new Argument());

With debug logging turned on, you'll see "argument created" from the constructor followed by "toString() invoked" and "hello @debug this is an argument". With debug logging turned off you'll only see "argument created" from the constructor. The "toString() invoked" won't be logged even though the level is info because the method isn't invoked.
